# Including all months in a year on x-axis using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a ggplot bar chart using the following data:

```
dispensed.date.start    dispensed.date.end    drug_class
2016-11-28              2016-12-07            opioid
2016-12-08              2016-12-15            benzodiazepene
2016-12-18              2016-12-26            MAT
2016-12-24              2016-12-31            opioid

#set levels, colors
status_levels <- c("Benzodiazepene", "MAT", "Nerve pain / Anticonvulsant", "Opioid", "Sedative", "Stimulant", "Death")
status_colors <- c("#984ea3", "#a65628", "#4daf4a", "#e41a1c", "#ff7f00", "#377eb8", '#000000')
```

Here's the plot:

```
timeline_plot<-ggplot(PDMP.data.clean,aes(x=dispensed.date.start, y=.2)) +
geom_segment(aes(x=dispensed.date.start, xend=dispensed.date.end, y=drug_class, yend=drug_class,col=drug_class), size=5)

# Don't show axes, appropriately position legend
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+theme(
                                   legend.position = "none"
)

# Display years
month_buffer <- 6

year_date_range <- seq(min(PDMP.data.clean$dispensed.date.start) - months(month_buffer), max(PDMP.data.clean$dispensed.date.start) + months(month_buffer), by='year')
year_date_range <- as.Date(
  intersect(
    ceiling_date(year_date_range, unit="year"),
    floor_date(year_date_range, unit="year")
  ),  origin = "1970-01-01"
)
year_format <- format(year_date_range, '%Y')
year_df <- data.frame(year_date_range, year_format)


 # Show year text on plot
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(data=year_df, aes(x=year_date_range,y=.9,label=year_format, fontface="bold"),size=2.5, color='black')

                                  
print(timeline_plot+ ggtitle(paste("Prescription History for Case # ",PDMP.data.clean$ndc))+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),aspect.ratio = 1/3.2,))
```

Here's the resulting plot:[image]

There's two things I'd like to fix but I'm not sure how:  First, how do I get each month to show up on the a-axis, instead of only every 3rd month the way it currently is shown?  Second, is there a way display the month without the year, since I'm already adding the year as text above the month of January?

Comment: Read about the `breaks` and `date_labels` arguments in `?scale_x_date`

Comment: It would be something like `scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%b")`. See the help for `strptime` for more on the date formatting codes.